# Inrush and steady state current in an Inductor with AC voltage

Tags: ac, inductor, electromagnetism

I have two statements here from two great men.

One says

"If you apply AC voltage to the solenoid at the peak of the waveform then there is little or no inrush current whereas if the solenoid is connected to an AC source as it passes through zero volts then the current waveform in the solenoid can reach an excessive value that causes magnetic saturation of the solenoid core and make the problem of inrush even worst"

other one says

"The transient depends upon the contact timing referred to the AC voltage applied, if the contact happens at any AC voltage peak, there is no transient at all (the current becomes a 90 degrees delayed wave straight away) while the transient will be maximized when the contact is achieved at any AC voltage zero crossing, the superimposed current will looks like an asymmetrical Gauss bell (very steeply at rising side)."

My question is why there is transient current or inrush current when a ac source is connected to an inductor at ac voltage zero crossing and why is there is no transient at ac peak voltage ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-9/practical-considerations-transformers/ start from Inrush Current.

Comment: Or try to think about it this way: "In the steady-state, when the sine wave voltage is going through zero (Vin = 0) in the positive direction, the inductor current will be a negative peak. But that can't happen when we first apply the sine wave of voltage at that point in the cycle (Vin = 0V), because the current in the inductor was zero just before we applied the voltage and it must also be zero just after we apply the sine of voltage. The way this can happen is to have a transient current. The transient current bridges the gap between the initial conditions and the steady-state.

Comment: But that transient isn't needed if the sine wave of voltage is applied at its peak, because then the current in the steady-state would normally be passing through zero (IL = 0A) at this time. No transient is needed to make both current to be zero and \$V_L=L*d i(t)/dt\$ be equal to the suddenly applied voltage."

Comment: And maybe I should point that this transient current in an ideal inductor will "only" have a peak value equal to \$2 I_{L(peak)}\$ at steady-state. As we can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Nbs.png 4A transient current and 2A steady-state current. We can also see that in steady-state when input voltage changes from 0V to +10V (into a positive direction), the inductor current is at the negative peak -2A.

Comment: you should not comment. rather you should answer. it will give you more points from me because many of your answers are quite acceptable to me.

Comment: please answer my this question @G36 . https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495579/current-wave-form-of-an-inductor?noredirect=1#comment1261431_495579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we plot the current that flows in an inductor, as a result of applying a voltage, we get the following.

This was prepared in response to somebody asking about inductor current, driven from a sinuosoidal source. The graph has been divided into several sections. The top traces plot the current from the zero crossing of the sinewave. The second traces plot the current from the peak of the sinewave. The difference between the two plots is shown below.

[image]

It's best to concentrate on the yellow/green traces first. Yellow is the sine voltage, but being applied at peak volts. The green current trace grows quickly while the voltage is high, flattens off as the voltage passes through zero, drops while the voltage is negative, and passes back through zero again as the voltage gets to its peak. This is the 'steady state' response. If the circuit had some loss in it, then any starting condition would eventually settle down to this current waveform, symmetrical about zero, and having zero average.

If we switch on at the voltage zero crossing, then we get the dark blue and orange curves. During the first quarter cycle of voltage, the current builds up. It will continue to build during the second quarter cycle.

We can sum these two parts together to get the overall voltage and current waveforms if we switch on at zero crossing, the purple and light blue ones. The current builds to a peak, and returns eventually to zero. The current never goes negative.

In a low permeability solenoid, so air-cored or with big air-gaps, this would not matter, except for the extra heating the higher current produced. However, if the solenoid is cored, and designed for a maximum current just above the peak of the steady state (green) current, then we can see that the peak light blue current exceeds this by a factor of two. Doubling the current in a saturable inductor collapses the inductance, maybe by two or three orders of magnitude, so the current now rises two or three orders of magnitude faster. This is the inrush.

Comment: i was asking why this happened but yes your stuff is quite true.

Comment: 'Why' is a tricky question in physics. Are you asking why reality is the way it is? The best I can do is show how simple equations model the behaviour we see. We either find that intuitive, and thus satisfying, or we ask 'but why that?' Current builds in an inductor in ways quantum electrodynamics predicts, charges exchange photons and all sorts of weird stuff. Unfortunately taking the question why to its logical conclusion could end up with 'why quantum mechanics', and nobody finds that intuitive. You need to decide what level model you're comfortable with.

Comment: yes you are right @Neil_UK . but i believe that even most complex things can be explained in layman terms. i try to do that and many times it work for me. you helpled me alot. thank you.